# Is it possible to fadeOut text without remove the line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My message code:**

```
$("#message").html(data).fadeOut(6000);
```

So I have a message that sent via a PHP file. Everything is good and the message displayed fine. Although it, there is one problem: When the message disappear, the line that the message was on it, disappear too, and then all my code above this line, moving a little bit and I don't want it.

So to conclude, my main question is how to make the message disappear, but not disappear the line that code is on it? Thanks.

As you can see, in the ***FIDDLE***: https://jsfiddle.net/dwe6mdhy/1/
Firstly we have 3 lines, and when the message fadeOut it removes the middle row.

Comment: I would render the message inside a div element/tag, when the message fades, the div stays in https://jsfiddle.net/dwe6mdhy/5/ this is something that's kind of flavour, there's a ton of solutions.. just pick the one who best suits you

Comment: The message is inside a span, is it good or not? @rmjoia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

```
$("#message").html("hello").fadeTo(6000, 0);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dwe6mdhy/6/

Comment: Simple and great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I had a problem. This is a contat form. And when I use your method, the message is displayed once, and if ill click submit again - it will not doing nothing... Just when I refresh the browser I can try again. Do you have any idea how to slove it? @guest271314

Comment: @WebR Try including `$("#message").fadeTo(0, 1)` within `submit` event handler

Answer (score 0):

Using `jquery` `animate` function and animate `opacity` like below instead of using `fadeOut`.

```
$("#message").html("hello").animate({opacity:0}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. I simply set a static height. And applied fadeTo to avoid removing the class.

```
<div id="message" style="height:15px;">

$("#message").html("hello").fadeTo(500,0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwe6mdhy/1/#&togetherjs=rL9qlJpiSL

Answer (score 0):

Just use **animation** instead `fadeOut`

```
$("#message").html("hello").animate({opacity: 0}, 6000);
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vorant/6y1w6arw/

after animation end `fadeOut` set `display: none` on element. Read the dock http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/